# Data overlapping

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, overlapping-data

Overlapping data are often present in time-series analysis and the academic studies mention about Heteroskedasticity and Autocovariance Consistent (HAC) estimators to solve this isssue, such as Newey-West (Harri & Brorsen, 2009). I would like to know if Cochrane-Orcutt estimator could also be employed with overlapping? Thanks!